# Where goes a Value type in an instance

Tags: c#, oop, heap-memory, stack-memory

As we all know, value types are stored in a stack. Now consider this:

```
class test
{
    public int Sum { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then create an instance as below:

```
test t = new test();
t.Sum = 10;
t.Name = "a string";
```

Now, how would the instance and its properties be stored in the heap?
As we have an int should be stored in stack.

Comment: you might want to check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011676/where-are-value-types-defined-in-a-reference-type-stored-heap-or-stack)

Comment: [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx) post by Eric Lippert might interest you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As we know value types are stored in stack.

A better way to put it would be "value types can be stored in the stack". The actual placement depends on the context.

Object of value types are stored on the stack only when you create these objects as local variables. When you make value-type objects part of other objects, value-type objects become part of their "owner" objects. Depending on the owner object type, the value-typed objects would be placed in the dynamic memory, as in your example, or on the stack, if `test` were declared a `struct`.

Comment: I thought my instance's value-typed variables are stored in stack and just a pointer in heap refers to them . thank you

Comment: *"Object of value types are stored on the stack only when you create these objects as local variables."* — even that is just an implementation detail and it isn't documented as the-only-one scenario. Value types can easily be stored in heap or somewhere else in future dotnet frameworks.