# When does a space for a variable get allocated on the stack?

Tags: c#

Is space allocated during declaration or initialization:

```
int c; // here

c = 5; // or here
```

Comment: Probably neither.  I'd think it would have to be allocated when the containing method is entered.

Comment: How do you know it's on the stack?

Comment: @lukas Because he's not using the `new` keyword I think and it is a value type not a reference type

Comment: @Joe consider struct Vector and the code Vector vec = new Vector(); we got new keyword and vec may go on stack. Good reading on subject http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx

Comment: local variables live on the stack. The objects they refer to may live on the heap.

Comment: @lukas I understand your point. The question isn't as clear as it should be

Comment: @David Heffernan: local variables don't live on the stack if they live in registers.

Comment: Note that it may never be allocated if code is inlined or usage is optimized away.

Comment: @eric ok there are always exceptions. And I guess you'd know! ;-)

Comment: If a local variable is captured by a lambda, it will be allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to clear the confusion that everytime value type is allocated on Stack memory only, please read below links.

Citing from articles below:

"A lot of confusion has been wrought by people explaining the difference between value types and reference types as "value types go on the stack, reference types go on the heap". This is simply untrue (as stated) and this article attempts to clarify matters somewhat. "

[memory allocation of value types and reference types in .net framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130468/memory-allocation-of-value-types-and-reference-types-in-net-framework)

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/memory.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the links.  They were helpful.

Answer (score 12):

> When does a space for a variable get allocated on the stack?

Your question presupposes that the storage for a variable is allocated on the stack. It need not be.  You just said "int a;" without indicating whether that was a local variable or a field, and without indicating other important information, like whether the local variable is a closed-over local of an anonymous function, or whether the block is an iterator block. In many of those scenarios no stack space is consumed by the variable because the variable is not short-lived.

Suppose for the sake of argument that the variable is a short-lived local variable. It still might not be on the stack. It might be enregistered, particularly if the jitter knows that it is on an architecture with lots of unused registers.

Supposing for the sake of argument that the variable is a short lived local variable and that the jitter has not chosen to enregister it, when is the stack space allocated?

Well, again, you are assuming that the jitter is using the stack as the temporary pool; though that is a convenient data structure, the jitter is allowed wide lattitude. The temporary pool could be allocated off of the heap, or there could be multiple stacks; some architectures support separating the data stack from the call stack in order to prevent stack-smashing attacks.

Supposing that the variable is a short-lived local variable and the jitter has chosen to not enregister it and the temporary pool is on the call stack, when is the stack space for it allocated?

Well now it depends on what you mean by "allocated". The entire million bytes of stack is reserved in the virtual memory system and committed aggressively, so the answer is "as soon as the thread is created, the stack space for everything that will ever go on the stack in this thread is allocated, and stays allocated." Of course it stays allocated *in the page file*. That stack isn't moved into hardware (RAM) until a page fault brings it in from the page file on disk.

If what you mean to ask is "when is the stack pointer bumped so that there is stack space specifically available for this local variable" then the answer is usually "as soon as control enters the method". Doing so can of course trigger that page fault I just mentioned.

I'm curious to know why you care. What difference does it make?

Comment: you describe when it is reserved. Is the question of when it is allocated even meaningful?

Comment: @David: You're right, I was being sloppy in my terminology. I'll try to clarify the text. This is a confusing question.

Comment: And even if `c` is stored on the stack, space may not be allocated for it if space for another local can be reused.

Comment: @Eric, thank you for the response. To answer your two questions.  I don't care, I was just curious.  The one thing that boggles me is that why is it that when I watch a video on someone professional explaining value types and reference types, they always say value types are allocated on the stack and reference types are allocated on the heap?

Comment: @Johann, why is this a pointless question?  We don't all work on the C# compiler team as Eric does and we some of us might be beginners.

Comment: @Xaisoft: I don't know why people think that. If you think about it for even a moment it becomes clear that not all variables of value type can possibly go on the stack because their lifetimes are too long. People seem to get this thing into their head and then repeat it without thinking critically.

Comment: @Xaisoft: I'm sorry, the words came out wrong. I meant to say something along the lines of "seemingly pointless but still of interest, simply becuase we're a curious species."

Comment: @Johann, No worries my friend.  I understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Eric, good comment, I now have a better understanding than before. Sadly this is one of those interview questions in which the interviewer thinks they have the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

The stack is allocated when the thread is created and then extended on demand, possibly terminating with a stack overflow.

Comment: apparently the stack memory isn't allocated when the thread is created. Well, you learn something new every day!

Comment: Your answer is on the right track but demonstrates a confusion between reserving and committing pages in a virtual memory system. In win32, creation of a thread reserves a million contiguous bytes of stack pages immediately. Those pages are bounded by guard pages which throw out of stack exceptions when hit.  In unmanaged code, stack space is automatically extended to *commit* the *reserved* virtual memory pages as the stack grows. In managed code, the pages are committed much more aggressively.  Remember, there is a  difference between reserving and committing pages; don't confuse them.

Comment: @eric you are quite right that my understanding of reserving, committing etc. is poor. I take it then that the stack is reserved when the thread is created but committed on demand? What do you mean by managed stacks being more aggressively committed?

Comment: Joe Duffy describes it better than I can. http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2007/03/10/TheCLRCommitsTheWholeStack.aspx. (Incidentally, I was *astonished* to discover that we do this; I am one of the people who was unaware of this oddity until relatively recently.)

Comment: @eric it does indeed seem odd. Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge. Reading that article, however, makes of even more acutely aware that I don't know enough about virtual memory. Always more to learn!

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: Ah, I see now that this was referencing stack memory specifically.  My answer addresses heap memory.  I'll keep it up for posterity, however.

I'm fairly certain it is during initialization, as if you have an object such as

```
IEnumerable<String> myVariable;
```

You could feasibly do:

```
myVariable = new List<String>();
```

You could additionally do:

```
myVariable = new Stack<String>();
```

And even more, you could make your own class filled with a ton of metadata requiring a huge amount of memory, and as long as you implemented IEnumerable correctly, you could do:

```
myVariable = new MyIEnumerableClass<String>();
```

Thus,(in the generic sense) until the variable is initialized, there is no way to actually *know* how much memory is needed.