# Are ints stored in memory the same as objects?

Tags: c#

When we declare an an like

```
int myInt = 5;
```

Is myInt is a reference to an object of type int.

Is that setting up a reference to the object the same way as if we setup a class?

```
StudentClass c = new StudentClass()
```

c is a reference and it points to the location of our Student Class?

And the only difference how it is treated when passed in paramaters.

I know how class objects work, just trying to understand primitive types.

Comment: If you read any beginner book on C#, you'd find these things out. Also Google surely knows the answer and it's been asked here more than once.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicated question. Please take a look at: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876503/memory-allocation-for-value-type-inside-reference-type-in-net - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130468/memory-allocation-of-value-types-and-reference-types-in-net-framework

Comment: @TonyTheLion, being able to get the answer "from google" doesn't make the question poor. If there is an exact duplicate of this question on SO, then link to it (or if enough rep, vote to close as dupe)

Comment: [The truth about value types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, an `int` is a value type (i.e. struct), so the variable contains the integer value itself, not a reference to an area where the value is stored.

Some more reading: [Types (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ewxz6et%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Read about the [difference between value types and reference types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)