# Where's the ValueType stored when CLR initialize the data structure to store them

Tags: .net, clr

I know Value Type instances stored in the stack and Reference Type instances stored in the heap. But, after the CLR ensure all the assemblies which define the Type have loaded, it will create some data structures to store the type object, the reference type object will stored in the heap, where's the value type objects stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Type` objects for different types are reference types, i.e. `Type` is a class, so they are all stored on the heap.

---

Note that value types are only stored on the stack if they are local variables in a method. If they are members of a class, they will be stored on the heap as part of the instance of that class.

Answer (score 0):

Value Type objects that are members of a Reference Type objects will be stored in the heap.

[This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876503/memory-allocation-for-value-type-inside-reference-type-in-net) Will help you to understand more.

Comment: I know this, but I don't mean value type objects or reference type objects, I mean Value Type and Reference Type themselves. before instantiate a class, the class itself will be stored in a data structure which create by CLR and allocate in the heap, but where's the Value Type stored?